# How can I effectively save a value in the OnPropertyChangedEvent?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm implementing MVVM and trying to save a value from my Xaml page's Switch. I would like to have this value stored into the Application's properties. Currently, saving the value where I am triggers OnPropertyChanged again, and the value is never updated.

I have a BaseViewModel class:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
            return;

        backingField = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
private bool _sizeToggled;
public bool SizeToggled
{
    get { return _sizeToggled; }
    set
    {
      SetValue(ref _sizeToggled, value);
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SizeToggled));
      SaveValue();
    }
}

private void SaveValue(){
Application.Current.Properties["SizeToggled"] = SizeToggled;
}
```

And my Xaml code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0,0,0">
    <Label Text="Size:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SizeToggled}" 
                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

How can I implement my SaveValue() Method so that the Application's Properties will be stored/updated when the value is updated?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Persistence  try to add this `Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync()`

Comment: Adding this helped, in addition to not saving multiple properties at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there's an issue when saving multiple Application Properties at the same time.
Separating the properties out of the save method and

> developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/… try to add this Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync() – Cole Xia

Forcing the save solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that the vm is really your datacontext?

Comment: Yes, my BindingContext is set correctly. My breakpoints are triggered properly in the ViewModel when the change is made. The issue is OnPropertyChanged is fired a second time when I call the SaveValue() method.

Comment: Yes, I've tried OneWay, OneWayToSource, and TwoWay. All have the same results.

Comment: My application requires this binding to be TwoWay, however as I am loading the value in and setting the Switch's binding value when the application loads.

Comment: you are calling on property changed twice..
one in the set and two in the setvalue. have you noticed it?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't have any effect on the state of the value.

Comment: try check the value right after setting it, the line below. is it saved?

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug with the Application Properties. Save method is triggered properly, and the value inside is correct. Value does save, just doesn't persist like expected.